# A question on multiplicative linear functional on Banach algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am reading a book about C*-algebra. But i am confused with some of its content. It says

Assume $A$ is a non-unital C*-algebra and $\tilde{A}$ is its unitization (the elements of the form $a+\lambda$). If $\phi: A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, is a nonzero homomorphism($\mathbb{C}$ denotes complex field), then $\tilde{\phi}(a+\lambda)=\phi(a)+\lambda~(a\in A$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb{C})$. Let $P(A)$ and $P(\tilde{A})$ denote the nonzero multiplicative linear functional on A and $\tilde{A}$, respectively. Thus, $P(A)$ is a subset of $P(\tilde{A})$. In fact, **$P(A)=P(\tilde{A})\cup\{\pi\}$**, where $\pi$ is determined by $\tilde{A}/A=\mathbb{C}$, i.e., $\ker\pi=A$. **Since $P(\tilde{A})$ is compact Hausdorff space, we conclude that $P(A)$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space.**

My question are

1. Does the "=" in the equation $P(A)=P(\tilde{A})\cup\{\pi\}$ is under the meaning of isomorphism? Is it topological isomorphism? Why?
2. Why does the $P(\tilde{A})$ is compact Hausdorff space implies that $P(A)$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to consider $P(A)$ as the set of all non-zero multiplicative linear functionals on $A$ with the weak$^*$-topology inherited from $A^*$, the dual of $A$. When $A$ is unital $P(A)$ is compact. So $P(\tilde{A})$ is always compact.

(1) It is $P(\tilde{A})=P(A)\cup \pi$. In fact, this equality reveals a more important fact which is $P(\tilde{A})$ is the one point compactification of $P(A)$.

(2) Yes. The reason is easy, because every compact subset of $P(\tilde{A})$ which does not contain $\{\pi\}$ (which is exactly the point at infinity) is compact in $P(A)$ too.

Comment: Could you explain more specifically ? I am a beginner of C*-algebra.

Comment: Actually, I have explained this topic in my lecture notes on $C^*$-algebra, which is available at arxiv:1211.3404. More specifically, see Section 3.1. Of course, I denote $P(A)$ by $\Omega(A)$.

Comment: Thanks you and also thanks for your book~ :)

Comment: (2) is not quite as obvious as you say; not every subspace of a compact space is locally compact.  (Consider $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ as a subspace of $[0,1]$.)

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thanks Nate, you are right. We have to use the fact that $P(\tilde{A})$ is the one point compactification of $P(A)$. Then every compact neighborhood of a point $x\in P(A)$ in $P(\tilde{A})$ which does not meet $\{\pi\}$ is actually compact in $P(A)$ too.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh: Sure.  Actually, all we really need is the fact that $P(\tilde{A})$ is open in $P(A)$.

Comment: The other way around

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh: Yes, sorry.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh Why every compact neighborhood of a point $x\in P(A)$ in $P(\tilde{A})$ which does not meet $\{\pi\}$, if $P(A)$ is the one point compactification of $P(A)$?

Comment: @Insomnia: It follows from the definition of one point compactification.